# Generate revision history with rcs-multi

Tags: revision-control

Is it possible to generate a page that collates all the revisions logs in multiple `tex` files with `rcs-multi`?

And while trying to understand the example file, the line

```
\rcsid{$Id: example.tex,v 1.2 2009/03/23 19:07:46 martin Exp martin $}
```

gets a

```
"File ended while scanning use of \rcs@striptrailingspace"
```

error. Why is that?

Comment: Hi Sydd999, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your question by using ticks and the {}. I also removed the thanks- it seems strange, but the best way to say thanks is to upvote any useful answers that you receive :) Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.